# Foward Call When Call Goes To Voicemail Using AMD (answering machine detection)

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, voice, twilio-twiml

I currently have my `twilio` number setup to forward the call to my personal cell whenever my `twilio` number is called.

I just have a redirect flow and 2 twiml bins that I have pasted below. One is for the forward the other is for a whisper.

I wanted to see if there is a way that I can use `Twilio's` AMD (`Answering Machine Detection`) to forward the call to my partner if I don't answer and the call goes to voicemail.

Can anyone help with this?

Call Forward:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Response>
    <Dial record ="record-from-answer">
    <Number url="https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EHf705c09133b3a34b64b8b0cf3d131068"> ###-###-####           
    </Number>
    </Dial>
    </Response>
```

Whisper:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <Response>
      <Say>By Design Home</Say>
     </Response>
```

Thanks for all help in advance I am still pretty new to this.

Comment: Where is the code where you have activated AMD?